# Updating git from a version without .git history

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, bitbucket

My collaborator is having trouble with git and we have decided to work on our unity project through unity collab.

I however, push milestones to bitbucket (git) to keep track of things.

My collaborator's version is synched through unity (not the `.git` files). If at some point, she needs to update the bitbucket, how do we do this as she hasn't pulled in a long long time (very different git indexed files).

If she pulls first, her changes would be lost right right? (and hers is the one we want)

if she commits with:

```
git add -A
git commit
```

and then pulls it would ask for a merge? Or give us an error?

Thanks for helping us figure out how to proceed.

Comment: This sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.  You are not using Git properly.  Ideally, both of you would be frequently pulling to and pushing from Bitbucket to both contribute your work and retrieve work done by the other party.

Comment: If your collaborator has not been pushing her work to Bitbucket, then how do you even know it happened, and what is the point of using Git?  Yes, she should complete her current work, and then push her current branch to Bitbucket, or possibly create a new branch, and push that.  You could open a pull request from her branch to `master`, and then see how messy the merge would be.

Comment: We tried that and she kept pushing before pulling and things got very messed up. Sigh. Alternatively, I can push to git as the only contributor to log the history, while she synchs through unity collab.

Comment: Does this unity connect fully synchronize files or there is still some diffrerence between yours and your collaborator's copy? If there is none then you can update the bitbucket repository youself.

Comment: The Assets and ProjectSettings folder are the ones that are common and those are the ones necessary for defining the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If she pulls first, her changes would be lost right right?

Actually, if the pull would overwrite files being modified, said pull would fail.

One way to ensure this is not the case is:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autostash true
```

That way, the work in progress is saved (stashed), local commits are replayed on top of the updated remote tracking branch and the work in progress is re-applied on top of the updated working tree.